# glassfish asadmin error in cmd, how can i solve this problem after all i did?

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm studying Java through a free course and during the class where we install and configure Glassfish, I'm giving an error in cmd when I use asadmin in the bin dir, I've seen comments and they all say the same thing (change the data in the asenv.config folder ) but nothing solved my problem.
[thats a cmd printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHgLC.png)

I already changed AS_Java in the asenv.config directory and the error still appears in cmd when I put asadmin in the bin dir.

If you need more images to understand the error you are giving, I can send them to you by email or in the comments.

Comment: What is the output when you run `java -version` on the command line? Will you please add that to the body of your question?

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _If you need more images_ Don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Post text. Use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format the text. It looks to me that the course you are studying is very old. Java 7 (which replaced Java 6) was released in 2011. That's more than 12 years ago. Have you even installed Java SE?

Answer (score 0):

Your GlassFish version is very old. Probably version 3, which requires Java 6. But you probably have a newer Java version.

Try using a newer version of GlassFish. You can download it from https://glassfish.org/download.html. The latest version of GlassFish 7.0.12 runs on Java 11 or newer.